# removing particular string from a specific tag in a file using ansible

Tags: text-processing, ansible

I need to delete a particular string from particular tag in a file using ansible,  as below you can see from `[pipeline:public_api]`  I need to remove `admin_token_auth`

```
    [pipeline:public_api]
    pipeline = cors sizelimit url_normalize request_id admin_token_auth build_auth_context token_auth json_body ec2_extension public_service
```

Desired outcome:

```
[pipeline:public_api]
pipeline = cors sizelimit url_normalize request_id build_auth_context token_auth json_body ec2_extension public_service
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the **[replace module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/replace_module.html)**. It is what I normally use for regular expressions in ansible:

> This module will replace all instances of a pattern within a file.

Something like:

```
- replace:
    path: /etc/keystone/keystone-paste.ini
    regexp: '^(pipeline = .*) admin_token_auth(.*)'
    replace: '\1\2'
```

Should work.

### EDIT:

Since that did not do the trick, I would instead use `sed` for this, and pass it to ansible with the `script` module.

First a simple `sed` script that gets the line number of your tag, and then does the change on the line *after* that tag. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get line number of tag
tagLine=$(sed -n '/pipeline:public_api/=' mohd.txt)

# The line we want to change is below $tagLine
editLine=$((tagLine+1))

# Do the actual replacement on the correct line
sed "${editLine}s/ admin_token_auth//" mohd.txt
```

### PoC:

Example file (`mohd.txt`):

```
cat mohd.txt 
    [pipeline:public_bar]
    pipeline = cors sizelimit url_normalize request_id admin_token_auth build_auth_context token_auth json_body ec2_extension public_service


    [pipeline:public_foo]
    pipeline = cors sizelimit url_normalize request_id admin_token_auth build_auth_context token_auth json_body ec2_extension public_service


    [pipeline:public_api]
    pipeline = cors sizelimit url_normalize request_id admin_token_auth build_auth_context token_auth json_body ec2_extension public_service

    [pipeline:public_abc]
    pipeline = cors sizelimit url_normalize request_id admin_token_auth build_auth_context token_auth json_body ec2_extension public_service
```

Running the script on `mohd.txt`:

```
./pipeline_public_api.sh 
    [pipeline:public_bar]
    pipeline = cors sizelimit url_normalize request_id admin_token_auth build_auth_context token_auth json_body ec2_extension public_service


    [pipeline:public_foo]
    pipeline = cors sizelimit url_normalize request_id admin_token_auth build_auth_context token_auth json_body ec2_extension public_service


    [pipeline:public_api]
    pipeline = cors sizelimit url_normalize request_id build_auth_context token_auth json_body ec2_extension public_service

    [pipeline:public_abc]
    pipeline = cors sizelimit url_normalize request_id admin_token_auth build_auth_context token_auth json_body ec2_extension public_service
```

As you can see, `admin_token_auth` was removed from the line *below* `[pipeline:public_api]`.


Now use the **[script module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html)** to execute that script on the hosts on your inventory. EXCEPT of course with the `-i` flag passed to `sed`, and the actual path and name to the file you want to change.

Comment: I need to remove content which is below `[pipeline:public_api`     which is `admin_token_auth`

Comment: Ok. Gotcha, see my edit.

Comment: it did not worked as per plan,  `admin_token_auth`  had 3 instances in the file and they all were removed, where i only wanted to remove it from a particular tag of `[pipeline: public_api]`

Comment: Hi any more thoughts on this????

Comment: Wow is it that difficult??? No answer from anyone!!

Comment: @Mohd You **do** realize we are all volunteers here, right?

Comment: Hey buddy I'm.not blaming any one,, I really searched alot,, and didn't found any answer,, niether any one could answer here,,, sorry if I offended u,, but I was wondering whether if there is any solution to this out there,, sorry once again..

Comment: Well, see my edit. That's how I would do it. Maybe you can do it another way in ansible, but when it comes to more advanced regular expressions, I always use the shell or script module in order to utilize the proper tools (`sed`, `awk`, `grep` etc).